# How to update list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing list using ul li. So I already have 4 list values and all values are null but one variable is getting some values so I want to replace it with the existing value.
**I am sharing my code.**

**JavaScript**

```
 var emptyLegend='<ul>
<li>red(0)</li>
<li>yellow(0)</li>
<li>green(0)</li>
<li>purple(0)</li>
</ul>'

var legend='<ul>
<li>red(3)</li>
</ul>'
```

variable legend is dynamic. If var legend has red(4),yellow(5) then output should be:

```
'<ul>
    <li>red(4)</li>
    <li>yellow(5)</li>
    <li>green(0)</li>
    <li>purple(0)</li>
    </ul>'
```

I want to replace red(0) with red(3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList"><li>red(0)</li>
<li>yellow(0)</li>
<li>green(0)</li>
<li>purple(0)</li></ul>

<p>Click the button to replace the first item in the the list.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("red(3)");
    var item = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[0];
    item.replaceChild(textnode, item.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is an idea you have to add your logic .
[More Info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_replacechild.asp)

Comment: I want to replace with li also

Comment: why you want to replace li